# Explicit sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{6+3^n}{6^{n+2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to find the sum of the infinite series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{6+3^n}{6^{n+2}}$$

So far I have managed to simplify the expression to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac {1}{6^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{9\cdot2^{n+2}}\right)$$.

The sum clearly converges as both expressions are equal to $0$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}$. Any tips as to how I may find an explicit expression for the sum of this series?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to find the sum of a geometric series?

Comment: "*The sum clearly converges as both expressions are equal to $0$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}$*"  This is a very incorrect way of thinking that you should correct as soon as possible.  Remember that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges despite the terms approaching zero.

Comment: Your reason for the sum converging is wrong. The sum does converge, but knowing that $a_n\to 0$ is not enough to prove $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: You've split it up correctly, but you need to remember about sums you know how to find the summation of...

Comment: Yeah sorry, I do realize that, and my argument was pretty sloppy as I'm just interested in finding the specific sum at this point. I do know the formula for finding the sum of a geometric series, but is this a geometric series?

Comment: It is the sum of two geometric series, yes.  Note that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{6^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{9\cdot2^{n+2}}\right)=\frac{1}{6}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{6^n}+\frac{1}{36}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: Thank you! That cleared it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned,it is geometric series $$\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  } \left( \frac { 1 }{ 6^{ n+1 } } +\frac { 1 }{ 9\cdot 2^{ n+2 } }  \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  } \frac { 1 }{ 6^{ n } } +\frac { 1 }{ 36 } \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  } \frac { 1 }{ 2^{ n } } =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ 6 } +\frac { 1 }{ { 6 }^{ 2 } } +... \right) +\frac { 1 }{ 36 } \left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ 2 } +\frac { 1 }{ { 2 }^{ 2 } } +... \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \frac { 1 }{ 1-\frac { 1 }{ 6 }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 36 } \frac { 1 }{ 1-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  } =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 5 } +\frac { 1 }{ 18 } =\frac { 23 }{ 90 } $$

Answer (score 0):

for the finite sum we have $$\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{6+3^n}{6^{n+2}}=-4/5\,{\frac {6+{3}^{k+1}}{{6}^{k+3}}}-{\frac {72+12\,{3}^{k+2}}{5\,{6
}^{k+4}}}+{\frac{23}{90}}
$$ now compute the limit for $k$ tends to infinity